# Mysql Stored Procedure and Php

Tags: php, mysql, stored-procedures, return-value

I have created this procedure:

```
 DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS add_com;
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE add_com (cd CHAR(16), n VARCHAR(20), t VARCHAR(20), i VARCHAR(20))
BEGIN
  DECLARE num INT;
  DECLARE msg varchar(20);
set @num=select COUNT(*) from commercianti where codice_fiscale=cd;
  IF num==0 THEN
    insert into commercianti values (cd,n,i,t);
    set @msg="Commerciante inserito";
  ELSE
    insert into errors values (1);
    set @msg="Commerciante presente";
  END IF;
return @msg;
END; //
```

then in a PHP page I execute this code:

```
 <?php
$cd=$_POST['codice_fiscale'];
$n=$_POST['nominativo'];
$t=$_POST['telefono'];
$i=$_POST['indirizzo'];
if(!$cd||!$n||!$t||!$i)
echo "No data";
else{
require dirname(__FILE__) . '/' . 'dbconfig.php';
$mysqli = new MySQLI(DB_HOST,DB_USER,DB_PASSWORD,DB_NAME);
$result = $mysqli->query("CALL add_com('$cd','$n','$t','$i')");
echo $result;
}
?>
```

But the value of $result is undefined and seems the procedure doesn't work or isn't called.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get data back from a routine, you should be using a function, rather than a procedure.  They have nearly the same syntax, but most notably is the `RETURNS type` section of the declaration.  Take a look at the official documentation:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-procedure.html

Note that the SECOND create block there is the one regarding functions.  The first deals with procedures.

So I think that would look something like this:

```
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS add_com;

DELIMITER //

CREATE FUNCTION add_com (cd CHAR(16), n VARCHAR(20), t VARCHAR(20), i VARCHAR(20))
RETURNS VARCHAR(20)
BEGIN
    DECLARE num INT;
    DECLARE msg varchar(20);

    SELECT COUNT(*) INTO @num FROM commercianti WHERE codice_fiscale = cd;

    IF num==0 THEN
        insert into commercianti values (cd,n,i,t);
        set @msg="Commerciante inserito";
    ELSE
        insert into errors values (1);
        set @msg="Commerciante presente";
    END IF;
    return @msg;
END; //
```

I'm not 100% sure about the `RETURNS VARCHAR(20)`.  That might have to be simply `RETURNS VARCHAR`.

Comment: Yes, I was arrive at the same conclusion, but still doesn't work. It doesn't return anything and also doesn't insert into commercianti, or error

Comment: @Tres: I forgot to edit the SELECT COUNT(*).  Try using a SELECT INTO statement instead (answer edited above).

Comment: The function is create correctly, but when it is used from php nothing happen

Comment: @Tres: I don't know php that well.  I can read it, but not write it.  Assuming you made the change to SELECT INTO, the only other thing I can think of is to add a semicolon to the end of your sql call in your php code: `$result = $mysqli->query("CALL add_com('$cd','$n','$t','$i');");`. Sometimes, if you don't include the `;`, The sql call will never actually be made since it is waiting for the end-of-statement delimiter.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing

```
IF num==0 THEN
```

to

```
IF num=0 THEN
```